# List Comprehension with for Loops in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following in python:

```
h = 0.05
p2 = [0,0]
p2[:] = [number - h for number in p2]
```

How would I define p2 using a regular for loop?

I initially thought that this would work:

```
for number in range(0,1,1):
    p2[number] = number - h
```

but that is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a transliteration:

```
h = 0.05
p2 = [0,0]

_result = []
for number in p2:
     _result.append(number - h)

p2[:] = _result

del _result
```

So *first* the list comprehension creates a list. Then that list is used to mutate the original list, (using a whole-slice index-assignment on the list being referenced by `p2`, this essentially just replaces the whole of the contents of `p2` with the whole of the contents from the data on the right-hand side.

If you *were* going to use a regular for-loop, though, you'd probably just do:

```
h = 0.05
p2 = [0,0]

for i, number in enumerate(p2):
    p2[i] = number - h
```

Answer (score 1):

h = 0.05
p2 = [0, 0]

for i in range(len(p2)):
p2[i] = p2[i] - h

This code will achieve the same result as your list comprehension approach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).